# definecolorset of xcolor --- problem with color values starting with "f"?

Tags: color

I am trying to write a script (that will be easy) to create a [`xkcd` color set](http://xkcd.com/color/rgb/) for the package `xcolor`. Look at this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} %
\definecolorset{HTML}{xkcd}{}{%
    OneColor,fcc2d9;%
    LastColor,56ae57%
}
\begin{document}    
\textcolor{xkcdOneColor}{OneColor}
\textcolor{xkcdLastColor}{LastColor}
\end{document}
```

...this will fail with:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
[...]
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   f
l.6 }

?
```

If I change the first `f` in `OneColor` to `a`, for example:

```
\definecolorset{HTML}{xkcd}{}{%
    OneColor,acc2d9;%
    LastColor,56ae57%
}
```

...now it works ok.

I understand I can circumvent this easily (seems that uppercase F does not create any problem), but I am curious: is it a bug or a driver (/me) error?

Comment: BTW, done --- it's at http://rlog.rgtti.com/2015/10/23/xkcd-color-list-for-latex-users/

Comment: I made a bug report.

Comment: @Johannes_B --- I also though about doing it --- where do you report bugs for LaTeX packages? Is there something centralized or is just a matter of emailing the author(s)? Thanks!

Comment: I it is a package bug, the package maintainer should be pinged. Email addresses are usually in the documentation or package source. If it is a LaTeX bug (i.e. `base` package), you can report bug on the project webpage. If you are not sure about a bug, you can always ask in our chat room. There is always somebody around picking it up.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a bug in `xcolor.sty`, where we find

```
283 \def\@hex@@Hex#1%
284  {\if a#1A\else \if b#1B\else \if c#1C\else \if d#1D\else
285   \if e#1E\else \if f#1f\else #1\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi \@hex@Hex}
```

and it's clear that it should be `\if f#1F`. So no `f` gets converted to `F`, which is expected when hexadecimal digits conforming to TeX's syntax are later needed (as arguments for `\number"`).

Indeed the input

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\def\@hex@@Hex#1%
 {\if a#1A\else \if b#1B\else \if c#1C\else \if d#1D\else
  \if e#1E\else \if f#1F\else #1\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi \@hex@Hex}
\makeatother

\definecolor{xk}{HTML}{fcc2d9}
\definecolor{XK}{HTML}{FCC2D9}

\begin{document}

A \textcolor{xk}{BCD} E

A \textcolor{XK}{BCD} E

\end{document}
```

produces the expected

[image]

Of course, expressing the HTML numbers in uppercase will circumvent the bug, too.

---

A possibly better patch is using `etoolbox`, that might be used in packages or classes (with `\RequirePackage{etoolbox}` in this case).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@hex@@Hex}{f\else}{F\else}{\typeout{Patching xcolor}}{}
\makeatother

\definecolor{DHBW-blue}{HTML}{026f93}

\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

Comment: Version 2.12 of `xcolor`, released 2016-05-11, has the correct code.