# How do I draw the dashed lines as shown in this figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the dashed lines as shown in the below figure:

[image]

I have achieved the following so far:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{zigzag/.style={decorate,decoration=zigzag}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (c) at (0,-2);
  \coordinate (d) at (4,-2);
  \coordinate (e) at (2,-4);
  \draw[thick,red,zigzag] (-2,0) coordinate(a) -- (2,0) coordinate(b);
  \draw[thick,fill=blue!20] (c) -- (b) -- (d) -- (e) -- (c);
  \draw[thick] (a) -- (c);
  \draw[thick,red,dashed] (0.8,0.08) -- (0,-0.8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The task is not so difficult with `decorations.markings`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{zigzag/.style={decorate,decoration=zigzag}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (c) at (0,-2);
\coordinate (d) at (4,-2);
\coordinate (e) at (2,-4);
\draw[thick,red,zigzag,postaction={
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.7 with \coordinate (x);
    },
    decorate
}] (-2,0) coordinate(a) -- (2,0) coordinate(b);
\draw[thick,fill=blue!20] (c) -- (b) -- (d) -- (e) -- cycle;
\draw[thick,postaction={
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.7 with \coordinate (y);
    },
    decorate
}] (a) -- (c);
\draw[dashed,red,thick] (x)--(y);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Bonus

Your entire figure:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings,calc,positioning}
\tikzset{zigzag/.style={decorate,decoration=zigzag}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (c) at (0,-2);
\coordinate (d) at (4,-2);
\coordinate (e) at (2,-4);
\draw[thick,red,zigzag,postaction={
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.7 with \coordinate (x);,
        mark=at position 0.5 with \coordinate (singularity);
    },
    decorate
}] (-2,0) coordinate(a) -- (2,0) coordinate(b);
\draw[thick,fill=blue!20] (c) -- (b) -- (d) -- (e) -- cycle;
\draw[thick,postaction={
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.7 with \coordinate (y);
    },
    decorate
}] (a) -- (c);
\draw[dashed,red,thick] (x)--(y);
\node[below left=1em and 1em of y,align=right,red] (es) {excision\\surface};
\draw[red,->] (es)--($(y)+(-.1,-.1)$);
\node[above=10ex of singularity,red] (sn) {singularity};
\draw[red,->] (sn)--($(singularity)+(0,1)$);
\node[below left=.5ex and 2ex of b] {$\mathcal{H}^+$};
\path (b) -- (d) node[midway,above right] {$\mathcal{I}^+$};
\path (d) -- (e) node[midway,below right] {$\mathcal{I}^-$};
\path (e) -- (c) node[midway,below left] {$\mathcal{H}^-$};
\node[right=0pt of d] {$i^0$};
\draw[postaction={
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.15 with \coordinate (enblue);
    },
    decorate
},thick,blue] (d) to[out=-150,in=-30] (c);
\draw[<-,thick,blue] (enblue)--($(enblue)+(-60:1)$)--($(enblue)+(-60:1)+(.2,0)$) node[right,align=left] {$t$ = constant\\in Schwarzschild\\coordinates};
\path[postaction={
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.35 with \coordinate (engren);
    },
    decorate
}] (c)--(b);
\draw[thick,green!50!black,postaction={
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.6 with \coordinate (enargr);
    },
    decorate
}] (d) to[out=180,in=-30] (engren);
\draw[thick,dashed,green!50!black] (engren)--($(engren)+(150:0.7)$);
\draw[<-,thick,green!50!black] (enargr)--($(enargr)+(60:0.75)$)--($(enargr)+(60:0.75)+(2,0)$) node[right,align=left] {$\tau$ = constant\\in Kerr-Schild\\coordinates};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you calculate  `mark=at position 0.7 with \coordinate (x);`. Is there an easy way to determine this value

Comment: Also, can you please explain `\draw[thick,red,zigzag,postaction={
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.7 with \coordinate (x);
    }` the meaning of the code

Comment: @subhamsoni You can see why I used 0.7 if you use 0.5 or 0.8 or 0.75. Looking at the revisions you can see that I originally used 0.8, but then I changed to 0.7 to fit your figure better.

Comment: Sure. can you please explain \draw[thick,red,zigzag,postaction={ decoration={ markings, mark=at position 0.7 with \coordinate (x); } the meaning of the code

Comment: @subhamsoni It is explained very well in section 50.5 of the [Ti*k*Z - PGF manual](http://mirror.kku.ac.th/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Comment: Lines are not always parallel with this way of constructing points. For example, if the position is 0.5, the lines are not parallel.

Comment: @JouleV - I get the error ! Package pgf Error: No shape named singularity is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.31   \node[above = 10ex of singularity,red]
                                              (sn) {singularity};

Comment: @AndréC Yes. If the position is 0.5, you have to change from 0.7 to 0.5 at two places.

Comment: @subhamsoni Have you retried? I can compile the code.

Comment: @JouleV By changing the position to 0.5 on both places, the line is not parallel, precisely!

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use the `intersections` library which allows to calculate the intersection point of 2 paths. Here the `zigzag` path and the `dashed` path.

To draw a dashed parallel, I used the `calc` library.

The principle.
I kept your path `\draw[thick,red,dashed] (0.8,0.08) -- (0,-0.8);` I shifted the starting point to the right by trial and error to find the right intersection.

I calculated the intersection named `i` of this path and the `zigzag`. Then I build a **parallel** path called `dash` through this point.

#### New version

Since the blue quadrilateral has right angles, to draw a parallel, I project orthogonally the point `i` on the `ac` side.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{zigzag/.style={decorate,decoration=zigzag}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (c) at (0,-2);
  \coordinate (d) at (4,-2);
  \coordinate (e) at (2,-4);
  \draw[name path=zz,thick,red,zigzag] (-2,0) coordinate(a) -- (2,0) coordinate(b);
  \draw[thick,fill=blue!20] (c) -- (b) -- (d) -- (e) -- (c);
  \draw[thick,name path=ac] (a) -- (c);
  \path[name path=trans] (.9,0.08) -- (0,-0.8);
  \coordinate [name intersections={of= zz and trans,by={i}}];
  % orthogonal projection of (i) on (a)--(c)
  \coordinate (l) at ($(a)!(i)!(c)$);
  \draw [thick,red,dashed] (i) -- (l);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Old version

I calculate the intersection of this path with the other side (the `ac` side) and draw the parallel segment `(i)--(l)`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{zigzag/.style={decorate,decoration=zigzag}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (c) at (0,-2);
  \coordinate (d) at (4,-2);
  \coordinate (e) at (2,-4);
  \draw[name path=zz,thick,red,zigzag] (-2,0) coordinate(a) -- (2,0) coordinate(b);
  \draw[thick,fill=blue!20] (c) -- (b) -- (d) -- (e) -- (c);
  \draw[thick,name path=ac] (a) -- (c);
  \path[name path=trans] (.9,0.08) -- (0,-0.8);
  \coordinate [name intersections={of= zz and trans,by={i}}];
  \coordinate (j) at ($(i)+(c)-(b)$);
  \coordinate(k) at ($(i)+(b)-(c)$);
  \path[name path=dash](j)--(k);
  \path[name intersections={of= ac and dash,by={l}}];
  \draw [thick,red,dashed] (i) -- (l);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: the line isn't at the exact location like in the picture

Comment: I just corrected that, is that okay with you?

Comment: can you please tell how did you calculate \path[name path=dash] (.9,0.08) -- (0,-0.8);

Comment: I renamed the paths so that the construction would be easier to understand. I'm looking for the intersection point between the `zz` and `trans` path. This point is called `i`, then I draw the parallel `[ik]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily calculate where a point in the middle between two other points lies:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc}
\tikzset{
    zigzag/.style={
        decorate,
        decoration={
            zigzag,
            amplitude=2.5pt,
            segment length=2.5mm
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \def\position{0.6}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
        \coordinate (c) at (0,-2);
        \coordinate (d) at (4,-2);
        \coordinate (e) at (2,-4);
        \draw[red, zigzag] (-2,0) coordinate(a) -- (2,0) coordinate(b);
        \draw[fill=blue!20] (c) -- (b) -- (d) -- (e) -- (c);
        \draw (a) -- (c);
        \draw[red, densely dashed, shorten >=0.5pt] ($(a)!\position!(c)$) -- ($(a)!\position!(b)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I accidentally found a code for the same diagram, on [TeXample.net](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/spacetime/). The author of the code, as written in the source code, is Jonah Miller. So I decide to post it as a CW.

```
% Horizon penetrating coordinates (vs. Schwarzschild coordinates)
% for a black hole spacetime, with excision
% Author: Jonah Miller
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzset{zigzag/.style={decorate, decoration=zigzag}}
\def \L {2.}

% fix for bug in color.sty
% see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274524/definecolorset-of-xcolor-problem-with-color-values-starting-with-f
\makeatletter
\def\@hex@@Hex#1%
 {\if a#1A\else \if b#1B\else \if c#1C\else \if d#1D\else
  \if e#1E\else \if f#1F\else #1\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi \@hex@Hex}
\makeatother

% Define a prettier green
\definecolor{darkgreen}{HTML}{006622}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  % causal diamond
  \draw[thick,red,zigzag] (-\L,\L) coordinate(stl) -- (\L,\L) coordinate (str);
  \draw[thick,black] (\L,-\L) coordinate (sbr)
    -- (0,0) coordinate (bif) -- (stl);
  \draw[thick,black,fill=blue, fill opacity=0.2,text opacity=1] 
    (bif) -- (str) -- (2*\L,0) node[right] (io) {$i^0$} -- (sbr);

  % null labels
  \draw[black] (1.4*\L,0.7*\L) node[right]  (scrip) {$\mathcal{I}^+$}
               (1.5*\L,-0.6*\L) node[right] (scrip) {$\mathcal{I}^-$}
               (0.2*\L,-0.6*\L) node[right] (scrip) {$\mathcal{H}^-$}
               (0.5*\L,0.85*\L) node[right] (scrip) {$\mathcal{H}^+$};

  % singularity label
  \draw[thick,red,<-] (0,1.05*\L) 
    -- (0,1.2*\L) node[above] {\color{red} singularity};
  % Scwharzschild surface
  \draw[thick,blue] (bif) .. controls (1.*\L,-0.35*\L) .. (2*\L,0);
  \draw[thick,blue,<-] (1.75*\L,-0.1*\L)  -- (1.9*\L,-0.5*\L)
    -- (2*\L,-0.5*\L) node[right,align=left]
    {$t=$ constant\\in Schwarzschild\\coordinates};
  % excision surface
  \draw[thick,dashed,red] (-0.3*\L,0.3*\L) -- (0.4*\L,\L);
  \draw[thick,red,<-] (-0.33*\L,0.3*\L) 
    -- (-0.5*\L,0.26*\L) node[left,align=right] {excision\\surface};
  % Kerr-Schild surface
  \draw[darkgreen,thick] (0.325*\L,0.325*\L) .. controls (\L,0) .. (2*\L,0);
  \draw[darkgreen,dashed,thick] (0.325*\L,0.325*\L) -- (-0.051*\L,0.5*\L);
  % Kerr-Schild label
  \draw[darkgreen,thick,<-] (0.95*\L,0.15*\L) -- (1.2*\L,0.5*\L)
    -- (2*\L,0.5*\L) node[right,align=left]
    {$\tau=$ constant\\in Kerr-Schild\\coordinates};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]