# rowcolor error in ubuntu

Tags: pdftex

In my tex file, in a table, I use `\rowcolor` with

```
\begin{table*}
\begin{tabular}{l l llllll}
...
\rowcolor[HTML]{e6f5f0} model & arch & 23 & 32 ...
...
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

This tex file is pdflatex-compiled with no error in Windows 10 while it is not so in Ubuntu16. It makes the following error:

```
Missing number, treated as zero. \rowcolor[HTML]{e6f5f0} model & ...
```

What is possibly wrong here, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The bug has been fixed by replacing `e6f5f0` by `E6F5F0`.

Please refer to [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274524/definecolorset-of-xcolor-problem-with-color-values-starting-with-f) for more details

Comment: as you show, that was fixed in the 2016 release, how old is your latex installation?

Comment: The age of the distribution probably expains why it works under Windows, but not under Linux: old distro under Linux, newer one under Windows.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015/Debian), indeed very old. I installed simply with tex live. The version of Ubuntu I am using is 16.